# Unable to find a suitable version for polymer

Tags: bower, polymer

I'm installing and configuring Polymer and i get to this:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for polymer, please choose one:
    1) polymer#master which resolved to ced408df76 and is required by core-component-page#a431519835, highlightjs-element#a2c5fc08d0, marked-element#761922b4a2 
    2) polymer#0.2.4 which resolved to 0.2.4 and is required by core-ajax#0.2.4, core-bind#0.2.4, core-collapse#0.2.4, core-doc-viewer#0.2.4, core-elements#0.2.4, core-firebase#0.2.4, core-icon#0.2.4, core-icons#0.2.4, core-iconset#0.2.4, core-iconset-svg#0.2.4, core-input#0.2.4, core-layout#0.2.4, core-layout-grid#0.2.4, core-layout-trbl#0.2.4, core-list#0.2.4, core-localstorage#0.2.4, core-media-query#0.2.4, core-menu-button#0.2.4, core-meta#0.2.4, core-overlay#0.2.4, core-range#0.2.4, core-selection#0.2.4, core-selector#0.2.4, core-theme-aware#0.2.4, core-tooltip#0.2.4, core-transition#0.2.4 
    3) polymer#~0.2.4 which resolved to 0.2.4 and is required by project

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

I'm still learning about and i dont know which one i should choose and why this problem happend. Can anyone explain me this tree options?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The recommended way to install Polymer 0.2.4 is through Bower. We’ve
>   chosen Bower because it removes the hassle of dependency management
>   when developing or consuming elements.

from http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html
I'd go with

> 2) polymer#0.2.4 which resolved to 0.2.4 and is required by
>   ...

This happened because when bower went to install a version of polymer it was presented with three options and didnt know which one to choose from. Many packages have a stable release and a development version, which you want is up to yourself. You can usually check up the packages on github or there websites to find which package might suit you best

Comment: I think this is the more likely option too, but i still dont really understand the differences...

Comment: They are github identifications - master is the master barnch of the polymer project on github. 0.2.4 is the latest stable release - as in this is the one where everything is tested and works as it should. and as for ~0.2.4 I dont have a certain answer but it could be another development project. but as I said 0.2.4 is the stable release - which for software dev is usually your best option - especially if youre not sure. Also this is the release you need for the components listed.